# What is this flight from Lyon St Exupéry (LYS) to Lyon Bron (LYN)?

Tags: flight-status

On the displays at LYS, a flight to LYN is mentioned. This is odd because the two airports are pretty close in distance, serving the same city (Lyon). Also, I was not able to find any info online about the flight.

Does anyone know if this flight is real and if so, what is the point of such a flight? Otherwise, if it's a mistake, where can it come from?

Screen display at LYS (dated 7 March 2019):
[image]
Text for line of interest reads as such:
EasyJet logo - 17:00 - Lyon Bron - EC 002 - Check-in - Terminal 1 - Check-in counter 11.

Comment: One possible explanation is a diversion: there was a flight originally scheduled to land at LYN, but there was bad weather or some other problem at LYN, so it diverted and landed at LYS instead.  The passengers disembarked.  When conditions improve at LYN, it will fly LYS-LYN to take the passengers to  their intended destination and so that it can make the next scheduled flight out of LYN.

Comment: @choster: 7 March 2019 (today). Will edit.

Comment: Lyon-Bron is only used for general aviation, and EasyJet only serves Lyon St Exupery. This is most probably some kind of mistake.

Comment: Had a look on flightrader24 and can't see anything on their (all other flights are shown). I can also find no record of any EasyJet flight having an EC flight code, they are usually displaced as U2 (like the Copenhagen flight) or EZY. As such I suspect it is a mistake but don't now how it happened or have any concrete evidence.

Comment: A slight correction to my previous comment - it seems EC flight codes are used for EasyJet Europe (rather then the larger EasyJet UK). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyJet_Europe

Comment: Does easyJet have a business arm like [SAS](https://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapid=112654227) does -- the latter is actually Lyon Bron based.

Comment: Another explanation could be a "flight" actually operated by a bus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur, probably an error, and the flight departures board from the [Lyon St Exupéry Airport website](https://www.lyonaeroports.com/en/flight-and-destinations/real-time-flight?date=2019-03-07#time=17&direction=departures&displayMode=tables) shows interesting stuff:

[image]

As you can see, that flight:

- only shows the destination airport code, when others show the destination name
- does not have a status

Interestingly, there's another flight to LYN at 18:00, with yet another airline and flight number. That one shows "Canceled", though. CCI may be the "Chambre de Commerce et d'Industrie", which is a local authority dedicated to business support, which is usually the (part) owner of airports in the area. In the case of LYS, the CCI of Lyon used to be the operator, and they now indirectly own 25% of the airport, so they are probably still involved in its operations.

Trying to click on any of those results in a blank page rather than the usual flight status details, which again seems to be an indication of incorrect data.

So either an error (manual input error, or a problem in some automated process), some kind of test, or maybe due to systems integration they had to do something funny to be able to display something specific on the screens of some check-in desk for whatever fun activity they may have been doing :-)

Answer (score 3):

Most likely this is an error.

First, no such flight appears on either flightradar24.com or flightaware.com.

Second, this "flight" is supposed to depart at 17:00 from gate 11, but there is an [actual EasyJet flight](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/EZY4425/history/20190307/1615Z/LFLL/EKCH) scheduled to depart at 17:05 from gate 11. It departed at 17:36.

Finally, the only recorded [flight between these two airports](https://flightaware.com/live/findflight?origin=LFLL&destination=LFLY) was indeed a general aviation flight by F-HCFX several days ago.

All this indicates to me that it was just an error.

Comment: I believe 11 is the check-in area rather than the gate (which would be in the last column, not yet shown for the flights from 16:45 on that picture). I believe the rest of the answer is still valid, though.